# Mongoose group by property in the last object of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following data:

```
[
    {
        name: "Alert 1",
        followusp: [
            {
                status: "new",
                date: "now"
            },
            {
                status: "do_it",
                date: "now"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Alert 2",
        followusp: [
            {
                status: "new",
                date: "now"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Alert 3",
        followusp: [
            {
                status: "new",
                date: "now"
            },
            {
                status: "engaged",
                date: "now"
            },
            {
                status: "canceled",
                date: "now"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Alert 4",
        followusp: [
            {
                status: "new",
                date: "now"
            },
            {
                status: "canceled",
                date: "now"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to group and get the **count** based on the status of the **last** object in **followups** array.
So for the example given, the result should be:

```
[
    {
        _id: "do_it",
        count: 1
    },
    {
        _id: "new",
        count: 1
    },
    {
        _id: "canceled",
        count: 2
    }
]
```

For now, I'm stuck with the following solution (it doesn't work):

```
query.push({ $group: { _id: "$followups.status", count: { $sum: 1 } } });
return dao.aggregate(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) and [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) passing `-1` which represents last array element to build your grouping key:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$followsup", -1 ] } },
                    in: "$$last.status"
                }
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WMCQzLCpfS9)